# How to use a WordPress' existing admin icon?

Tags: menus, add-menu-page, icon

I use the `add_menu_page` function to add an new admin menu:

```
add_menu_page(
    'Custom_menu',
    'Custom_menu',
    'edit_posts',
    'custom_slug',
    '',
    'wordpress_existing_icon',
    5
);
```

How to use one of WordPress' existing icons?

For instance, if I would like to use the "Posts" WordPress icon, by what must I replace `'wordpress_existing_icon'` in the code above ?

I tried `'edit'` and `'edit-posts'` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Short answer is that you can't. Not only using add_menu_page like that. Those icons WordPress uses are added as background images via CSS, not using the icon_url method that is provided with add_menu_page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`add_menu_page();` as far as I can tell does not work with `screen_icon` or the default CSS parameters. The `$icon` paramater only takes 2 options, an `url` or `div` (well 3 if you leave it empty), so that leaves you with these options:

1. Hard-code the link to the icons which are located in `wp-includes/images/wpicons.png`. This is an image slice of all the icons.
2. Just cut out the icon you want in a photo editor and include it as a stand-alone image in your plugin folder like the codex example.
3. Use the `div` parameter and define it via CSS. For example;

-

```
 add_menu_page(
               'custom menu title', 
               'custom menu', 
               'add_users', 
               'myplugin/myplugin-index.php', 
               '', 
               'div', //this part
               6);
```

---

To elaborate on the previous answer when using `screen_icon('edit');` here is the list:

- edit
- upload
- link-manager
- edit-pages
- edit-comments
- themes
- plugins
- users
- tools
- options-general

You can also contain them in a div like :

```
<div id="icon-edit" class="icon32"></div>
```

Style reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/User:Wycks/Styling_Option_Pages:

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this code is working for me :

```
add_menu_page( 
    __( 'Test Book', 'testbook' ),
    'Test Book',
    'manage_options',
    'includes/admin-options.php',
    'test_book_menu_page',
    'dashicons-building',
   7
);
```

I simply added 'dashicons-building' as shown in the code above.

[image]

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/resource/dashicons/

Answer (score 1):

When you call the `screen_icon` function, put the page id from which you want to get the icon. For instance, if you want posts icon, use either `screen_icon('edit');` or `screen_icon('post');`

About here, you can leave it to `false` or `null` or maybe put "div" here. I read somewhere in the codex that "div" should be used whenever there's supposed to be some custom CSS

Comment: Sorry but there are problably something I don't understand. I can't use screen_icon('edit') function in my add_menu_page() function ? I want the small "Posts" icon before the label of my 'Custom_menu'

Comment: not in this function, i meant in the function which outputs the html for the page