# Issue on Setting $icon_url Parameter on WP add_menu_page()

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, add-menu-page

I am trying to create a custom Menu by using the WordPress `add_menu_page()` function. I think I understand the whole function parameters as Codex point it out as:

```
<?php 
      add_menu_page( $page_title,
                     $menu_title,
                     $capability,
                     $menu_slug,
                     $function,
                     $icon_url,
                     $position ); 
?>
```

The only problem which I have is how to point to an existing WP icons liketool, edit, upload and so on.., in $icon_url? I already find [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69925/how-to-use-a-wordpress-existing-admin-icon) but I coulnt' figute it out how to add style to `div` at:

```
 <?php 
        add_menu_page(
               'custom menu title', 
               'custom menu', 
               'add_users', 
               'myplugin/myplugin-index.php', 
               '', 
               'div', //this part
               6);
  ?>
```

inside of my `.php` file?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69925/how-to-use-a-wordpress-existing-admin-icon) you provided has the answer, given by [Otto](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/2232/otto) as a comment:

> Short answer is that you can't. Not only using add_menu_page like
>   that. Those icons WordPress uses are added as background images via
>   CSS, not using the `icon_url` method that is provided with
>   `add_menu_page`.

As you said the syntax is:

> **syntax:** add_menu_page( $page_title*, $menu_title*, $capability*, $menu_slug*, $function, $icon_url, $position );    -    * required

So I used my custom icon (`home.png`), placed in a folder (`/my_theme/admin/images/`) as:

```
add_menu_page(  
    'Site Options',                     // The title to be displayed on the corresponding page for this menu  
    'Site Options',                     // The text to be displayed for this actual menu item  
    'manage_options',                   // Which type of users can see this menu  
    'sandbox',                          // The unique ID - that is, the slug - for this menu item  
    'sandbox_menu_page_display',    // The name of the function to call when rendering the menu for this page
    get_bloginfo( template_directory ) . '/admin/images/home.png'   // Icon for the Main menu in Admin panel
);
```